# SQL Server 2008 - 2016 datetime remove milliseconds globally

Tags: sql-server, datetime

I recently migrated a database from SQL Server 2008 to 2016.  One of the side effects is that a raw output of a datetime field now contains milliseconds whereas before it didn't.   Is there a way I can globally change this behaviour so a simple select * would output it without milliseconds.

Comment: Is the data type on the field different after the migration?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Create a view that casts the data to a datetime2 datatype without the milliseconds. Then use that view for your joins if you so desire.

Or you can change the datatype of that column to a datetime2 type that does not have the millisecond precision and rebuild the table.

Comment: Specifically, a `datetime2(0)`.